# How do I connect to my own flask server properly?

Tags: python, html, flask, web

The code I currently have is something like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "welcome to my page"


app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

When I try to run the code on Pychar I get the following results:

```
"C:\Users\radbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/radbo/yay.py
 * Serving Flask app "yay" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 161-701-749
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

"
```

Instead this is returned:

```
Hmmm… can't reach this page It looks like the webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8080/ might be having issues, or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

My question is as follows:
Is my server connectable or does it not exist?

Answer (score 0):

In Flask (and other server technologies) `0.0.0.0` is a convention that means "bind on *all* addresses". However, `0.0.0.0` is not a valid address for your browser to reach a destination.

That means your flask server will bind to, among any other addresses your system has, to its loopback address `127.0.0.1` (which the alias `localhost` will almost always point to).

So in your browser, you should use http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://localhost:8000

If your machine has other IP addresses associated with it, you can also reach it on those IP addresses, provided that firewall rules permit the traffic.

Note that using `0.0.0.0` means that your webserver will also respond to requests that come from other clients on your network, particularly when using `debug=True` which can pose security risks if exposed, which obviously may not be desirable. If you're only going to use the webapp locally on your own computer, consider using `host=127.0.0.1`

[reference](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/)